# How to move/edit labels?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I need to move/edit few labels in a job.
How can I work on it?

I am using QGIS 1.7.4 and the label option in the toolbar (not the layer options)

Comment: This feature was only added in 1.8.  You might have to update in order to use this.

Comment: Dear Nathan, I am not able to find this option. I need to move/rotate/edit few labels.

Comment: well, just updated to 1.8 but no way to find this option...